# Wacom One being used as a monitor when off

Tags: multiple-monitors, wacom-one

I have a Wacom One, which I sometimes use I don't want to have on all the time (afraid of burn-in). The problem I'm having is that when I turn it off, it's still detected as a monitor, so, sometimes, when Windows starts a new application, it's put in the Wacom One, and I'm not aware of it because it's off. The only way I have around it is to manually unplug the USB-C cable on the tablet.

Is there a way for Windows to stop using it as a monitor when I turn it off?

In case it matters, I'm running Windows 10, and my video card is an Nvidia GTX 1080.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think this issue is specific to your setup - Windows and multi monitors have always been a little funky. Ive never found a good solution, but this is best ive come up with:

1. Physically unplugging the monitor (video cable) - Windows notices, my other monitors flicker and all open windows are re-arranged onto my remaining 2 screens. Works, but its kind of a rubbish solution.
2. What i mostly do is put up with it, and use keyboard shortcuts to bring the window into view when i need them.

---

Try the following commands, it will demonstrate how to get hold of a window and move it (if you can see it or not).

So we're on the same page to demo this, run these commands to open Explorer:

- Keyboard shortcut [MICROSOFT KEY] + [R] - opens Run dialog.
- type `explorer`. Press [ENTER] key - File explorer opens

At this point File Explorer is open and is the active Window on the Taskbar, now try the following.

- Keyboard shortcut [ALT] + [SPACE] - opens the `system menu` on File Explorer window

You cant move a window if its maximised. But you can maximise and restore a window like this:
(only while the `system menu` is still open, [ALT] + [SPACE] first to re-open)

- Press [X] key - maximises file explorer window

OR

- Press [R] key - restores file explorer window if maximised (it can now be moved)

OR

- Press [M] Key - cursor will change and jump to the window (if window not maximised).
  Use the arrow keys to move the window around / you can also move the mouse after you use one of the arrow keys. Hit [ENTER] to "let go" of the window and the cursor returns to normal.

This wont work with some types of application (eg full screen media players/games and some "skinned" applications etc) but it mostly works - functionality has been around forever. Theres a bit of trial and error to figure out of the window is maximised or not if you cant see it, but ive gotten pretty quick with practice.

Probably also worth mentioning:

- Keyboard shortcuts [ALT] + [TAB] and [ALT] + [SHIFT] + [TAB] to cycle forwards/backwards through open windows